# Use Tab key to set focus on an angular material Tab

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am new to Angular-Material. How can you set the focus on an Angular-Material tab when focused on a button (Add Accomplishment) within one material tab to another angular material-tab using the tab key.

> AppResource.Component.html

```
<button mat-button>
Add accomplishment
<button>
```

> ResourceDetail.component.html

```
<mat-tab-group
    <mat-tab label ="engagment">
            <app-resource-view> <app-resource-view>
     </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Skill" >
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following what you explained, I understand that you need to change your tab of your parent component when you click on a button in your child component.

To do so you can use a service where you will listen to a subject.

This way you can say something from your child component, and then get the value on your parent component.

On your service

```
listener: Subject<boolean> = new Subject;
```

This is the subject that allow you to chat between your two components

On your child component, when you click on the button, you need to say to your subject that you want to do something. For the example, the `Subject` is made of `boolean` but you can made it of `string`, `number` or whatever you want.

```
chat(){
  this.resourceService.listener.next(true)
}
```

And then on your parent component, you can check if the subject has changed and perform something following the change.

```
selected: number = 0

ngOnInit(){
  this.resourceService.listener.subscribe((val) => {
    if (val){
      this.selected = 1
    }
  })
}
```

Here, `selected` is the index of the `mat-tab-group`'s tab

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-udypuv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fresource-detail%2Fresource-detail.component.ts) for better understanding

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question for clarity, I meant using the tab key, set the focus on an Angular-material tab. I am looking for a simple solution, ideally not involving a service.

Comment: Ok right, what do you mean by tab key ? And also by set the focus on Angular material tab ? The tab key is the index of the selected tab ? And setting the focus is like changing the selected tab of a second tab ?

Comment: the tab key on your computer keyboard. Not sure how to make set focus on Angular-Material tab more clear. Maybe I mean the material tab label.So I would Like to set the selected tab to the second one.

Comment: Oh ok I see, I will try to make a stackblitz with this, all your need is just to change the selected tab when we use tab key so ? The button have no action related to the tabs ?